# Percentile formula in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, percentile

I have a range of numbers I am trying to summarize using percentiles; 10th and 90th to weed out the outliers and then 25th, 50th, and 75th to demonstrate the distribution within the range. The range ($A$2:$A$260) is 259 numbers from -72.21 to 0.79 and includes duplicates, notably several 0s.

The 10th percentile lands between the 5th and 6th of 7 total 0s with the next highest number being 0.03. Using the formula =PERCENTILE($A$2:$A$260,0.1), Excel returns a value of 0.027. While this is technically correct, I am unclear how Excel came up with this number when it seems like it could have come up with literally any number between 0 and 0.03.

I've included an image of the values surrounding what I would have expected to be the 10th percentile. Can anyone shed light on how 0.027 is the value returned in this situation? Is there a way to round this so it returns the nearest value that actually exists in my range?

[10th percentile surrounding values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koaSB.png)

Comment: How Percentile calculates its result is described in [the documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/percentile-function-91b43a53-543c-4708-93de-d626debdddca). What more do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

From the Excel documentation:

> - If k is non-numeric, PERCENTILE returns the #VALUE! error value.
> - If k is < 0 or if k > 1, PERCENTILE returns the #NUM! error value.
> - If k is not a multiple of 1/(n - 1), PERCENTILE interpolates to determine the value at the k-th percentile.

So since your k=0.1 is not a multiple of 1/258, it is taking 25/258 (which is 0.097) and 26/258 (which is 1.008) so it is interpolating between these, closer to the k=25/258 value.

Answer (score 0):

The percentile function works out a value h from the number of points (N) and the required percentile (p) - referred to somewhat confusingly as k in the Excel documentation - according to the formula

```
h = (N − 1) p + 1
```

If you apply this to your situation you get

```
h = (259-1) * 0.1 +1

  = 26.8
```

This means that the percentile lies "0.8 of the way" between point number 26 and point number 27, i.e. its value is

```
0 + 0.8 * 0.033323

=  0.27 approximately.
```

Plz see the last table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) for more detail.

If you wanted to calculate h for yourself in Excel, it would just be:

```
=(COUNT(A:A)-1)*0.1+1
```

---

So to answer the second part of your question, if you wanted to get a value that actually existed in your range, you could choose to round h up or down and then use it to index your list of numbers:

Rounding down (which gives you 0):

```
=LET(h,(COUNT(A:A)-1)*0.1+1,INDEX(A:A,ROUNDDOWN(h,0)+1))
```

Rounding up (which gives you 0.3323):

```
=LET(h,(COUNT(A:A)-1)*0.1+1,INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(h,0)+1))
```

where you have to add 1 because your list starts in A2.

[image]